# Замена символа в массиве и выделение памяти под массив

Tags: c++, c, массивы, строки, память

Почему не работает 5 строка, и почему работает 8 строка, если не выделена память под B?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    char* A = (char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
    A = "123\0";
    A[0] = '1'; //5 строка

    char* B;
    B = "123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789\0"; // 8 строка
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Всё Вы врёте, работает она.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Почему не работает

Что значит "не работает"?!  Вы **должны** были описать *ожидаемое* и *получаемое* поведение. Телепатов здесь нет - улавливать Ваши мысли некому.

Подозреваю, что Вы просто не понимаете **как** это работает. На самом деле, в языке С/С++  запись лексемы вида "это строка" означает инструкцию компилятору выделить 11 байт памяти, в первые 10 поместить текст, заданный в кавычках, а в последнюю - ноль символ. Вот и всё...

Кстати говоря, добавлять явно ноль-символ '\0' в конец текстовой константы не нужно - компилятор это и сам сделает.

Оператор вида

```
char *cptr;
```

инструктирует компилятор выделить 4 байта под **переменную**, которая является указателем на строку.  Поэтому, когда Вы пишите

```
A = "123\0";
```

то это означает, что указатель, лежащий в переменной *А* теперь указывает на строку "123\0" а предшествующее присвоение

```
A = (char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
```

соответственно, теряет всякий смысл т.к. нигде не используется.

Именно поэтому, ваше утверждение о том, что *не работает*, оно тоже - не очень понятно...

Answer (score 1):

Вы не указали, что значит "*не работает*", будем догадываться...

Вероятно, вы компилируете ваш код как С++ (а С и С++ - **разные** языки) - в этом случае он не будет компилироваться, так как строковый литерал рассматривается как `const char []` - т.е. константный, неизменный массив символов. И поэтому его нельзя присваивать переменной `char*` - потому что так легко нарушить константность, присваивая что-то через этот указатель.

В пользу того, что вы компилируете как С++, есть косвенная улика - приведение `(char*)` при `malloc` - при компиляции в режиме C оно не нужно.

**Содержимое** строк в С/С++ вот так

```
A = "123\0";
```

не копируется, см. функции типа `strcpy`.

Вот ваш код, скомпилированный как код C - https://ideone.com/MC0zuQ.

Что до *работы* - под которой обычно программисты понимают *время выполнения* - то тут просто ничего не делается, так что умный оптимизатор может просто вообще выкинуть весь код :)